# Python - User input not creating new list item (instead adds string to end of most recent item)

Tags: python, list, input

Here I have some code for a basic 'to do' list program that allows the user to add, edit, show, or delete (complete) items. After typing 'add' the user can type a string that should be taken as input and added as a new list item, however for some reason the first input is taken, creates a list item, and then any other input is added as additional text to the most recent list item, rather than creating a new list item.

```
todos = []

while True:
    # Get user input and strip space characters from it
    user_action = input("Type add, show, completed, edit, or exit: \n")
    user_action = user_action.strip()

    if 'add' in user_action or 'new' in user_action:
        todo = user_action[4:]

        with open('projectFiles/todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        todos.append(todo)

        with open('projectFiles/todos.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todos)

    elif 'show' in user_action:
        with open('projectFiles/todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        # new_todos = [item.strip('\n') for item in todos]

        for index, item in enumerate(todos):
            item = item.strip('\n')
            row = f"{index + 1} - {item}"
            print(row)
    elif 'edit' in user_action:
        number = int(user_action[5:])
        print(number)
        number = number - 1

        with open('projectFiles/todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        new_todo = input("Enter new 'to do': ")
        todos[number] = new_todo + '\n'

        print('Here is how it will look', todos)

        with open('projectFiles/todos.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todos)

    elif 'completed' in user_action:
        number = int(user_action[9:])

        with open('projectFiles/todos.txt', 'r') as file:
            todos = file.readlines()

        index = number - 1
        todo_to_remove = todos[index].strip('\n')
        todos.pop(index)

        with open('projectFiles/todos.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.writelines(todos)

        message = f'List item called \'{todo_to_remove}\' was removed from the list'
        print(message)
    elif 'exit' in user_action:
        break

    else:
        print('Please enter a valid command.')

print('Bye')
```

For example, with the input:

```
add Clean
add Phone call
```

I am expecting after typing 'show' for the list to display as:

1 - Clean

2 - Phone call

Instead it displays as:

1 - CleanPhone Call

I tried removing the 'with context managers' that read and write the list to a .txt file, but that didn't seem to be affecting anything and I am unsure what else could be causing the issue as I had it working previously and don't remember changing or deleting anything.

Essentially I'm looking for some clarity as to why my "if 'add' in user_action or 'new' in user_action:" block cannot create more than one list item and why every subsequent input adds to the first list item. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of posting, and then editing, please use the preview before posting.

Comment: Lines in a text file are defined by the presence of newline characters.  Where are you writing a newline to the file when adding a new item?  The string you get from `input()` won't have one, even if you didn't apply `.strip()` to it.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, I added a newline character in the todos.append(todo) and that seemed to solve the issue, although I'm not sure if that is the best way to go about it.